# Gradle is unable to locate the bintray repository for kotlinx-serialization

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I am trying to use `kotlinx.serialization` and have had just *no* luck.  Here is the pertinent portion of the `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven("https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx")
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

This dies on the vine:

```
Could not find method maven() for arguments [https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx] 
on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler
```

[image]

What is an up-to-date way to incorporate `kotlinx-serialization` ?

Comment: It looks like the actual version for kotlinx.serialization is 1.3.70, not 1.3.71

At least their master branch depends on 1.3.70 kotlin components

Comment: @user3159253  Please add that as answer: it fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the actual version for kotlinx.serialization is 1.3.70, not 1.3.71 At least their master branch depends on 1.3.70 kotlin components

Answer (score 2):

The arguments of method maven in `org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler` is Closure,and the context object is type `org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository`,so the correct script would be like

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   maven {
    url="https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx"
  }
```

}
what's more,`kotlinx.serialization` exists in mavencentral,so there is no need to add your custom maven repository

Comment: The `bintray` url was added as one of a number of attempts to find the thing..

Comment: I guess he/she's using build.gradle.kts, not build.gradle. I have similar constructs in perfectly valid projects

Comment: @user3159253 what's your gradle version

Comment: Your points are valid (and I upvoted). Turns out the `kotlinx` version is one minor-minor tick behind and @user3159253 found that: I asked him to create an answer.

Comment: I"m excited about `kotlin`.  I'm a team-lead level scala developer as my main language for five years until `python` last year. Dislike python for anything but a wrapper for the great `numpy` and friends libraries. Language itself is quite weak. `kotlin` gives 90% of value of `scala` but is more approachable so I can try to use it in scenarios with java folks.

Comment: @neo we've switched to 6.3, but the code of the buildsystem hasn't been changed since 5.x, at least since mid-2019

Comment: @javadba actually I used to be a python guy, but all my recent projects are kotlin ones ;-)

Comment: doing `kotlin` you'll understand a bit of where i'm coming from. `for comprehensions` solve 20% of the collections processing problems. We're left to our own devices for the rest.  Oh and don't even get me started about multithreading.